# multiple upload image function php?

Tags: php, file-upload

Hi there I want to make a function for me to able upload a multiple image in one submission below are my code structure:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Image1 :<input name="image1" type="file" /></p>
  <p>Image2 :<input name="image2" type="file" /></p>
  <p>Image3 :<input name="image3" type="file" /></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

include('configdb.php');

$uploadDir = 'upload/';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$fileName = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['image1']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['image1']['type'];

$image1path = $uploadDir . $fileName;


$result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, "$image1path");
if (!$result) {
echo "Error uploading";
exit;
}

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    $image1 = addslashes($image1path);
}



$sql="INSERT INTO picture (image1, image2, image3) VALUES ('$image1','$image2', $image3)";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

}
```

Basically my code above does one image upload, How can I make a function to be able upload 3 images.

Comment: `foreach ($_FILES as $name => $file)` would be a start...

Comment: You're neglecting to check for upload errors and assuming everything worked fine. Bad way to go... very bad.

Comment: @MarcB I will add a validation after test upload of 3 images works fine :) If you can help I really appreciate it thanks :)

Comment: `if ($_FILES['image1']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { ... upload failed ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to multiple upload image. You can upload more than 3 images.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Image1 :<input name="image[]" type="file" /></p>
  <p>Image2 :<input name="image[]" type="file" /></p>
  <p>Image3 :<input name="image[]" type="file" /></p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
include('configdb.php');

$uploadDir = 'upload/';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $image = array();

    foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $index => $name) {

        if($_FILES['image']['error'][$index] == 4) {
            continue;
        }

        if($_FILES['image']['error'][$index] == 0) {

            $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'][$index];
            $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$index];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'][$index];
            $fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'][$index];

            if(($fileType == "image/gif"   ||
                $fileType == "image/jpeg"  ||
                $fileType == "image/pjpeg" ||
                $fileType == "image/png"   ||
                $fileType == "image/x-png") && 
                $fileSize < 500000) {

                $imagePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

                $result = @move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $imagePath);
                if (!$result) {
                    echo "Error uploading";
                    exit;
                }
                $image[] = $imagePath;
            }
        }
    }
    // Save images to database
    $nbImage = count($image);
    if($nbImage) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO picture (image1, image2, image3) VALUES (";
        for($i=0; $i<$nbImage; $i++) {
            if($i) $sql .= ",";
            $sql .= "\"".$image[$i]."\"";
        }
        $sql .= ")";

        @mysql_query($sql);
    }
}

?>
```

Note: you should test the type and the size of image before upload it because of the security.

Comment: I test the your code but it doesnt work it said undefind photo then I replace it with "image" like in form file filed. but it doesnt work :(

Comment: I just edit your form. You didn't add name="submit" why it doesn't work. :)

Comment: I copy your code and try it again but it doesnt work too, It doesnt save image in directory and in database

Comment: i already test it and it works well. you should check your permission upload directory. Also you can try to print error to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
...
$images = array();
foreach (array('image1', 'image2', 'image3') as $name) {
    $images[$name] = new stdClass();
    $images[$name]->fileName = $_FILES[$name]['name'];
    $images[$name]->tmpName  = $_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'];
    $images[$name]->fileSize = $_FILES[$name]['size'];
    $images[$name]->fileType = $_FILES[$name]['type'];

    $images[$name]->path = $uploadDir . $images[$name]->fileName;

    $result = move_uploaded_file($images[$name]->tmpName, $images[$name]->path);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Error uploading";
        exit;
    }

    $images[$name]->sql = mysql_real_escape_string($images[$name]->path);
}

$sql="INSERT INTO picture (image1, image2, image3) VALUES ({$images['image1']},{$images['image2']},{$images['image3']})";
...
```

Comment: @Petah, it must be stdClass instead of stdObject

Comment: @Petah I recieve this error Fatal error: Class 'stdObject' not found in C: and when I comment out the //*$images[$name] = new stdObject();
 and I recieve this error Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value. thanks

Comment: @robert I change what you said and I receive Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 and with this in line of sql statement Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in