# Curious problème with images upload in PHP from form

Tags: php, arrays, filesize

I try to upload pictures from a form in PHP.

I've got a strange problem regarding my images upload:

My form:

```
<form id="booking-step" method="post" action="add.php" class="booking" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="AddPhotos1" name="AddPhotos[]" />
<input type="file" id="AddPhotos2" name="AddPhotos[]" />
<input type="file" id="AddPhotos3" name="AddPhotos[]" />
<input type="file" id="AddPhotos4" name="AddPhotos[]" />
<input type="file" id="AddPhotos5" name="AddPhotos[]" />
</form>
```

My PHP:

```
if($_FILES['AddPhotos']){
    $errorAddPhotos = "";
    $validAddPhotos = "";
    for($x=0;$x<sizeof($_FILES["AddPhotos"]["name"]);$x++){
        $fichier = basename($_FILES['AddPhotos']['name'][$x]);
        $taille_maxi = 3000;
        $taille = filesize($_FILES['AddPhotos']['tmp_name'][$x]);
        $extensions = array('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg');
        $extension = strrchr($_FILES['AddPhotos']['name'][$x], '.'); 
        if(!in_array($extension, $extensions))
        {
             $errorAddPhotos .= "Wrong extension.<br />";
        }
        if($taille>$taille_maxi)
        {
             $errorAddPhotos .= "Wrong size.<br />";
        }
        if((in_array($extension, $extensions)) && ($taille<$taille_maxi))
        {
             $fichier = strtr($fichier, 
                  'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 
                  'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');
             $fichier = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '-', $fichier);
             if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['AddPhotos']['tmp_name'][$x], $destin . $fichier))
             {
                  $validAddPhotos = 'Success!';
             }
             else
             {
                  $errorAddPhotos = 'Wrong';
             }
        }           
        }
    }

echo $validAddPhotos;
echo $errorAddPhotos
```

My code looks good, but I cant upload my files...

Error: my files stay in condition "if(!in_array($extension, $extensions))".

Could you please help ?

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of browser are you using?

Comment: I use Safari. Thanks.

Comment: try to print out your variable $extension and what did you see? is it the same as your array $extensions? also, looking to your upload files' name.

Comment: print_r(strrchr($_FILES['AddPhotos']['name'][$x], '.')) echo .jpeg

Comment: So yes this is the same as my array $extensions cause .jpeg is in array.

Comment: I ran your code, I didn't get any error the same as yours ( "if(!in_array($extension, $extensions))" ). :-/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [this logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264445/multiple-upload-image-function-php#answer-8264565) is more perform than yours with testing image type and file size. Also, you can custom it with what you want like you did name of the file :)

[multiple upload image function php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264445/multiple-upload-image-function-php#answer-8264565)