# multiple image upload.....not working

Tags: php, file-upload

I am willing to upload multiple image but having strange problem..
I am using this simple code...

```
<?php
require("query/config.php");
$p_id=$_POST['place_id'];
$file=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
print_r($file);
echo "hghghg";
foreach($file as $key=>$val)
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"/upload/" . $val); 
$query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into city_gallery set place_id='$p_id',image='$val'") or die("Alert! Query failed.");

}
```

this is code not working and not displaying anything on upload.php page if i dont use foreach loop... for example if i have only this code on upload.php.. it display...

```
<?php
require("query/config.php");
$p_id=$_POST['place_id'];
$file=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
print_r($file);
echo "hghghg";
```

here output is...`Array ( [0] => 86662.jpg [1] => beautiful-girl-baby-hd-images.jpg [2] => [3] => ) hghghg`

so its mean the array of image is present on this page...but when i use the top above code with `foreach` it display nothing on this page and also not moving image in upload folder and not the image name is going in database,

here is my form..

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                         <?php

                         include("query/config.php");
                         $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from cite_guide order by id desc");
                         ?>
                         <select id="place_id" name="place_id" >
                         <option value="0">Select Place</option>
                         <?php
                         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                         {
                         ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['place']; ?></option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                                </select>
                            <fieldset>Image 1

                                <input type="file" class="input-medium" name="image[]" />
                            </fieldset>
                           <fieldset>Image 2

                                <input type="file" class="input-medium" name="image[]" />
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>Image 3

                                <input type="file" class="input-medium" name="image[]" />
                            </fieldset>


                            <fieldset>Image 4

                                <input type="file" class="input-medium" name="image[]" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="submit-green" type="submit" value="Upload" />
                            </fieldset>

                         </form>
```

**Now image name is going into database but image not moving to upload foldar...for image i corrected this**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/upload/" . $val);
```

to

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"/upload/" . $val);
```

now only image is not moving...why????

any idea why this is happening ...please suggest...Thanks

Comment: see my updates...form is there

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES['image'])` - for multiple files it has different structure than for 1 file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264445/multiple-upload-image-function-php Check out the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264445/multiple-upload-image-function-php#answer-8264565).

Comment: that is not my question... @showdev

Comment: You're not trying to upload and process multiple files from an array `image[]`? The answer to "why is this happening" is that you are not traversing the array correctly. Look at the structure of the posted array and then look at how you are traversing it. The answer I referenced does it correctly. If this is not what you are asking, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your time, it was a problem of looping...I replace `foreach` loop to `for` and my script is running now, the main problem i faced with foreach loop to traversing `$_FILES` array, And like `temp_name` contain the temprory name for each file. So i made some thing like this..

I changed this code:
From

```
foreach($file as $key=>$val)
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"/upload/" . $val); 
$query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into city_gallery set place_id='$p_id',image='$val'") or die("Alert! Query failed.");

}
```

To

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($file);$i++)
{
$file=$_FILES["image"]["name"][$i];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$i],"/upload/" .$file); 
$query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into city_gallery set place_id='$p_id',image='$val'") or die("Alert! Query failed.");
}
```